# trouble with tmp directory on travis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, travis-ci

I have a job, the code is:

```
class Job
  @queue = :default

  class << self
    def perform
      temp_file = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'my_temp_file')
      return if File.exist?(temp_file)
      FileUtils.touch(temp_file)

      begin
        # ....
      ensure
        FileUtils.rm(temp_file)
      end
    end
```

It's perfectly fine on local, but fails on travis with:

```
Failure/Error: LateNotificationJob.perform
     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/travis/build/something/something/tmp/my_temp_file
```

What is the solution? Please help!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566884/rubys-file-open-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-text-txt-errnoenoent-er/6566912#6566912

Answer (score 0):

`tmp` directory is probably not checked in to your repo, but your local copy of the repo has it. For travis, which starts blank, either some Rails initializer or another codepath needs to create that directory before attempting to create the file in that directory. 
Or you could simply checkin an empty `tmp` directory with your repo.

Here's similar question and answer - [Heroku - how to write into "tmp" directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253031/heroku-how-to-write-into-tmp-directory)